# Checking the output for a condition and returning a value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

the below query takes the count from two tables and divides them to get a number (I am using a cross join for this).

I want to check if the result is greater than zero. If its greater than zero, then output a custom message, else return null. How can i achieve this?

```
select r.cnt / o.cnt
from (select count(*) from table_A) r
cross join
(select count(*) from table_B) o;
```

Comment: use case when pls.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp can refer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement to check if the result of the division is greater than zero and output a custom message or return null accordingly.

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN r.cnt / o.cnt > 0 THEN 'Custom Message'
    ELSE NULL
  END
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_A) r
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_B) o;
```

This query checks the condition r.cnt / o.cnt > 0 and, if true, outputs 'Custom Message'; otherwise, it returns NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this Query :

```
SELECT  CASE
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_A ) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_B ) > 0 THEN 'Custom Message'
ELSE NULL END FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier done with a variable..

```
set ratio=(select count(*) from table_A) / (select count(*) from table_B);

select case when $ratio>0 then 'custom message' end as out_message
```